# Add HDD to Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am a beginner. I have installed Ubuntu 20.4 LTS as a dual-boot to my machine. I have installed it into SSD as can be seen on below at nvme0n1p4 partition. However, I wanted to add an HDD partition sda6 to my Ubuntu. I found its UUID and edited the fstab accordingly as can be seen below. However, I have two questions in my mind right now.

1-When I try to store something in the UbuntuStorage partition, it denies me. I gave the error below. How can I solve it?

```
efe@efeASUS:~/Downloads$ mv /home/efe/Downloads/Quartus-pro-18.1.0.222-linux.tar /storage 
mv: cannot create regular file '/storage/Quartus-pro-18.1.0.222-linux.tar': Permission denied
```

2-Also I cannot find this partition in my Files GUI. How can I find it? I can find it from terminal but not from GUI.

```
efe@efeASUS:~/Downloads$ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL         UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/canonical-livep
loop1       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg
loop2       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/core/10823
loop3       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/snap-store/518
loop4       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/snapd/11036
loop5       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/vlc/2103
loop6       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/core18/1988
loop7       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804
loop8       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/gtk-common-them
loop9       squashfs                                                          0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804
sda                                                                                    
├─sda1      ntfs     Recovery      A0425D5B425D36EE                                    
├─sda2      vfat                   605E-DF19                                           
├─sda3                                                                                 
├─sda4      ntfs     Arşiv         7250BDD450BD9F73                                    
├─sda5      ntfs                   8AE4DCF2E4DCE20D                      102,4G    74% /media/efe/8AE4DCF2E4
└─sda6      ext4     UbuntuStorage 83b4cd29-d013-4cc7-836c-8de0e027d8a6    138G     0% /storage
nvme0n1                                                                                
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p2 ntfs                   182E0ED52E0EAC36                                    
├─nvme0n1p3 vfat                   C708-8912                             504,2M     2% /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p4 ext4                   7142db43-56d2-40c9-b9b9-ec1a44cb0505     11G    65% /
```

```
efe@efeASUS:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=7142db43-56d2-40c9-b9b9-ec1a44cb0505 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=C708-8912  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=83b4cd29-d013-4cc7-836c-8de0e027d8a6 /storage ext4 defaults 0 2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the file permissions? Your `/storage` location may be owned by `root`. If this is something that only your user account will use, then you may be able to resolve it with `sudo chown -R efe:efe /storage` 

Comment: @Matigo Thank you. It resolved my first problem.

Comment: The second problem isn't a problem, because partitions are mounted to locations. They don't appear as separate devices like USB sticks, network drives, and the like 

Comment: @Matigo yeah I sensed it coming :D However, how can I also see it in GUI? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this for the mount point to have it mount in your /home/user_name/storage, hopefully that shows up as a normal user not trying to access files/directories in the / file system.

```
UUID=83b4cd29-d013-4cc7-836c-8de0e027d8a6 /home/user_name/storage ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Do not even need to reboot, `umount /storage`, then a `mount -a` after the editing. Checking again for the permission on the new directory. Oh and a `mkdir /home/user_name/storage` needs to be done to have the mount point before the mounting of it.

Comment: An alternative is to link you folders in /storage into /home. I put all my folders like Music, Documents, etc into my data partition and then link each folder back into /home. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk  Also shows examples of setting ownership & permissions.